# How to use apt-get install in ubuntu

Tags: apt

I have tried many link and none of them works for me. I have internet access in my college through a proxy 172.16.24.4 with port 3128 and the proxy type is either http or https. I want to use apt-get to install softwares on ubuntu. Please help me. Please explain in detail as I am fairly new to ubuntu.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set apt-get proxy open `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and add this line to the bottom of file.

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
```

Or if you need a username and Password:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
```

To set system wide proxy (not just apt) open `~/.bashrc` and add this to the bottom of file.

```
http_proxy=http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport
export http_proxy
```

You can find more information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Setting_up_apt-get_to_use_a_http-proxy).